# WEKA Preprocess and Predicting student grade

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, weka

I'm working on an application that performs prediction for each year based on the student grades. The grades of the student ranges from 70 to 97. My dataset contains student grades from 1st year to 5th year:
GWA1 - 1st Year General Weighted Average
GWA2 - 2nd Year General Weighted Average
and so on, until GWA5

I'm planning to use J48 for the prediction.

I have different issues,

1. My dataset contains different student year level. If the student is currently in his 4th year, then GWA4 and GWA5 are zero. Should I only take graduated students? (students who have GWA1-GWA5).
2. There are courses that offers up to 4 years only. Their GWA5 in their dataset is 0.
3. The program also needs to predict the grade in his current year. For example, for a 2nd year student, the program predicts the GWA2. For a 4th year student, the program predicts the GWA4.
4. How do I preprocess the data? Should I classify the grades to a grade label such as Excellent, Average, Poor?

Sample Dataset:

```
GWA1     GWA2     GWA3     GWA4     GWA5
83.6     87.5     90.2     89.1     91.2
76.4     78.2     77.6     80.9     79.4
93.6     91.5     92.7     91.1     92.7
```

Comment: Can you add more detail, for example, sample dataset?

Comment: added a sample dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most importantly, your dataset is not [tidy](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). Columns need to be converted to rows , e.g. into this table layout:

`student year gpa passed
s1      1    83.6 yes
s1      2    76.4 no
...`

I made the "passed" column up. But this design is easier for J48 to work with, in its default configuration. WHich is, to classify categorical or binary variables - J48 can't handle numerical attributes in the "class" attribute (= the To Be Predicted attribute).

I'm not sure if you can also predict numerical values  with J48. I think weka and the dataset need to be tweaked quite a bit.

Check the customization dialogs, read the documentation, and google "classification by regression". Or better yet, use the LinearRegression classifier instead of J48.

I  any case, in the "Filter" panel, you need to add the "AddClassification" supervised-instance-filter, and then set its "Output Classifications" option to True.

Comment: If I will use regression, the dataset is the same right? I will just remove the passed column?

Comment: Yes. The table schema should look like the one I sketched, without the made-up "passed" column. The numerical predictions you'd get from linear regression can still be way off. Depends on data quality and the preprocessing steps yo can apply. Maybe gather more info, about the whole subject matter, on your own first.